# CMake cannot find wxWidgets library on macOS High Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, wxwidgets

I was learning CMake and wanted to try it out to compile a test wxWidgets application, which I previously successfully compiled under Windows. However, I've never used CMake before, but back then I set it up using Visual Studio manually.

So I looked at some tutorials online, and compiled a basic hello world application (command line) in C++ using CMake, and it worked fine. Then I installed wxWidgets using brew.

```
brew install wxmac
```

It did install and I could run the `wx-config` tool successfully. I can also see the files in the finder. Then I added this to my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
project(wxWidgetsTest)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base wxSTC wxAUI REQUIRED)

include( "${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}" )

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    )

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

But however, when I tried to generate the build files, I'm using the command:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

And it fails saying that `find_package` cannot find the wxWidgets library. This is the error output:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:953 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

The wxWidgets library is installed at /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.4/

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you can use `SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.4/)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, but it didn't work either. I got the same error.

Comment: As you are learning CMake I ask the obvious question: did you deleted the `CMakeCache.txt` after the proposed changes? Results of a `find_package` call are cached and you might not see the expected result from your changes. And while you are at it. Please switch the order of the `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` call. The `cmake_minimum_required` influences some initial settings in the `project` call.

Comment: @vre Yes I did. I was deleting the entire build folder and rerunning the cmake command. And thanks for the second tip by the way. Did it but no changes either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After six hours of fiddling, I found a new configuration option in the findWxWidgets script which is a needed configuration.

All I had to do is to specify the location of the `wx-config` file.

> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. -DwxWidgets_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.4/bin/wx-config

And it was able to find the wxWidgets library. Seems to be a simple error on my part.

This is the source where I found: http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Can-t-find-wxWidgets-tp7591015p7591017.html

Comment: If you look at `/usr/local/bin/wx-config` you will see it is a symbolic link to the binary you specified above. So, if you use this link, it will always point to the latest version you installed with **homebrew**, whereas the one you specified may become outdated. Just a thought.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That isn't always true. I've read that macOS comes with binaries of older versions of wxWidgets, and the ones in local bin refer to those older binaries. Dunno how true is this, but I guess this is the reason, since it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

considering it a bug...

to work around, set CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH to help cmake find the program.
put following line before find_package(wxWidgets).

`set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/usr/local")`

I find suspecious code in FindWidgets.cmake with comments

> ## Support cross-compiling, only search in the target platform.

and it provide ONLY_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH option to find_program command.
According to documentation, this option means only find program under 'root' path.